# kubernetes dashboard graphs not shown for some nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 1 master + 3 worker nodes

Kubernetes dashboard not showing graphs(Memory + CPU) for some of the PODS.

```
Client Version: version.Info{
Major:"1", 
Minor:"12", 
GitVersion:"v1.12.2",
GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740",
GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:54:59Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.10.4", 
Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
Server Version: version.Info{
Major:"1", 
Minor:"12", 
GitVersion:"v1.12.2",
GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740",
GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:43:59Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.10.4", 
Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see Nodes in Kubernetes dashboard, you need go to submenu Cluster/Node as shown in screenshot in this link (not to Pods).
[Kubernetes UI Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccA7.png)

For more Information please visit: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

I hope it will be useful for you

Comment: hi @coolinuxoid, if you observe the screenshot I attached graphs are not shown for one of the POD(memory + CPU). That is the issue i am facing

Comment: please run `kubectl get pods <problematic-pod> -o wide` then find node which is hosting this problematic pod, then run `kubectl describe node <nodename>`, and check if under "Non-terminated Pods:" section, this pod had any CPU or Memory request. If it shows `0(0%)` on each column, then nothing to do with dashboard. If yes, probably some dashboard stuck, you can refresh it or terminate and start it again to check